# DBI begin_work doesn't work with stored procedure calls

Tags: mysql, perl, stored-procedures, dbi, autocommit

I am trying to make a call to a stored procedure from with in a transaction in its simplified form:

```
my $dbh= DBI->connect(............  );  

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("call sp_get_workitems (1,1)");
$dbh->begin_work  or die $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute();
my ($result)= $sth->fetchrow_array();

$dbh->commit;
```

this gives the following error :

```
DBD driver has not implemented the AutoCommit attribute
```

If I replace the begin_work statement with  `$dbh->{'AutoCommit'} = 0;` (before or after the prepare),  I get this error:

```
DBD::mysql::db commit failed: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

If I replace the stored procedure call with a simple select statement it all works fine.

The stored procedure includes a number of updates and finishes with a select statement.
Of course it would be easier if I could handle the transaction within the procedure put I need to action some perl code if rollback occurs.

I'm using ActivePerl on windows 7  and an amazon cloud instance running Centos with DBI 1.616 installed, this occurs on both.

Should this work or is there a way around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you explicitly `finish()` every executed prepared procedure CALL before you explicitly `commit()` the transaction.  E.g.,

```
$sth->finish;
$sth->commit();
```

This appears to be a bug to me, given the typical semantics of `finish()`.  Multiple result sets, calling `more_results`, etc. did not matter.

DBD 1.616, DBD::mysql 4.020 and MySQL 5.5.19.

Comment: Note for all : If you're using Prepared Statements, don't forget to call the ->finish method on the PS handlers before committing OR rolling back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AutoCommit => 0`, then you don't need `begin_work()`. Everything is in a transaction until you `commit()` or `rollback()`. Then a new transaction begins.

Actually, you should connect with `RaiseError => 1`, because you should get an error on `begin_work()` when `AutoCommit` is 0. From the fine docs:

> If AutoCommit is already off when
> begin_work is called then it does
> nothing except return an error. If the
> driver does not support transactions
> then when begin_work attempts to set
> AutoCommit off the driver will trigger
> a fatal error.

Also, what version of `DBD::mysql` are you using? I think the latest version does implement `AutoCommit`.

Comment: As I said I replaced the begin_work statement with autoCommit=>0, never used them together , however neither work with the stored procedure.  I'm using DBD::mysql 4.019