# perl mySQL procedure with insert and select fails when in transaction

Tags: mysql, perl, transactions

This is my perl code:

```
my $dbc = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:test', "entcfg", "entcfg") || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
$dbc->{TraceLevel} = "2"; #debug mode
$dbc->{AutoCommit} = 0; #enable transactions, if possible
$dbc->{RaiseError} = 1; #raise database errors

###sql commands
my $particle_value = $dbc->prepare('CALL particle_test_value(?,?,?,?)');
my $particle_name = $dbc->prepare('CALL particle_test_name(?,?,?,?)');
my $table_test = $dbc->prepare('CALL table_test(?,?,?)');

sub actionMessage {
    my ($sh,$msgobj) = @_;

    my @result;
    my $return_ID;

    eval {
        $table_test->execute(undef,"value","value"); #new item
        $return_ID = $table_test->fetchrow_array(); #get new row id
    };
    if ($@) {
        warn $@; # print the error
    }
}
```

The mySQL transaction is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `table_test`(
    v_id INT,
    v_name VARCHAR(255),
    v_value VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test (name,value) VALUES (v_name,v_value);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

If I put `$dbc->commit;` after the `execute` or the `fetchrow_array`,I get a **`Commands out of sync`** error.
If I remove the `AutoCommit` line, the code works but I can't use transactions.
If I try to change `AutoCommit` during the sub, I get this error:**`Turning off AutoCommit failed`.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6454840/132382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract values from stored procedures like that.

Make table_test a function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `table_test`( 
    v_name VARCHAR(255),
    v_value VARCHAR(255)
) RETURNS integer
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test (name,value) VALUES (v_name,v_value);
        RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();       
END //
```

and have $table_test use it like a function:

```
my $table_test = $dbc->prepare('SELECT table_test(?,?,?)');
```

edit: MySQL stored procedures can actually return results - the result of a SELECT statement inside the procedure is sent back to the SQL client.  You have found a bug in DBD::mysql.  The above works as a workaround.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for improving my knowledge of mySQL!

Comment: Misleading.  MySQL procedures *can* indeed return result sets, and DBD::mysql understands how to fetch them.  There is a bug in the perl driver, however, under AutoCommit=0

Comment: My apologies.  I read in the MySQL docs that procedures "can only pass back values using output variables", and went with that.  I have amended my answer.