# MySQL "command out of sync"

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Ok, I already fixed, anyway I don't know why it work... :P

my first code was:

```
my ($sth,$rc);
eval{
  $sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL mysp(?,?)');
  $rc = $sth->execute(1,2);
  if    ($rc eq '1'){# ok}
};

if($@){
  $dbh->rollback;
  warn $@;
}else{
  $dbh->commit;
}
```

It stop with mysql error "Commands out of sync" on commit

```
eval{
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL mysp(?,?)');
  my $rc = $sth->execute(1,2);
  if($rc eq '1'){# ok}
};

if($@){
  $dbh->rollback;
  warn $@;
}else{
  $dbh->commit;
}
```

After localized `$sth` and `$rc` into `eval{}` it works... why?

Comment: Implicit `$sth->finish` added by `$sth` going out of scope???

Comment: Looks a lot like the problem described in [DBI begin_work doesn't work with stored procedure calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6454840). [pilcrow's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10001508/176646) was to explicitly call `$sth->finish()` before committing the transaction (jives with what @ikegami said).

Answer (score 0):

ikegami's answer is correct.

You need to call $sth->finish(), this is done implicitly as it goes out of scope with the eval{} block.